# How do I make a collapsable mobile menu disappear with a bigger screen?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to make a responsive menu that has a mobile collapsable menu. The menu is only shown on the click of a toggle button. If I start the screen as small and click to show the menu, when I expand the browser, it still shows even though I have display: none; and visibility: none; at the large media queries. However, if I start the screen big, make it small, click the toggle button, and expand again it does what I expect it to. Here's the jsfiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/dptbqc1e/#&togetherjs=JEpaO4q27M

```
<header class="header">
        <a class="logo" href="index.html">Blog.</a>
        <ul class="nav nav_big-screen">
            <li class="nav__item">
                <a class="nav__link" href="#">Home</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav__item">
                <a class="nav__link" href="#">About</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav__item">
                <a class="nav__link" href="#">Blog</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <img class="toggle" src="img/nav.png">
        <ul class="nav nav_small-screen">
            <li class="nav__item">
                <a class="nav__link" href="#">Home</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav__item">
                <a class="nav__link" href="#">About</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav__item">
                <a class="nav__link" href="#">Blog</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </header>
```

I only put that HTML here because it said I had to. Everything else is in the jsfiddle. Thanks, I hope this makes sense!

Comment: Unless I misunderstand you, it's working properly for me. Regardless of initial window size, at no point do I have both small-screen and large-screen navigation showing up when toggled on with Chrome 52.0.2743.116 (64-bit).

Comment: Using jquery toggle is basically the equivalent of setting an inline style on the menu item's display property which is going to override your CSS as inline styles will do.  Thats why your media queries won't work after you've toggled, and then resized your window.  One way to prevent that is to listen for the Window's resize event, and handle setting the display property on the menu according to the window size.

Comment: Robert, that makes sense. I thought it was something along those lines since it depended on the starting window size. Do you know the jquery for that?

Comment: works fine for me..

Comment: I just figured it out. Stupid mistake. I had visibility: none; instead of visibility: hidden;. That fixed it.

Comment: should also mention a lot of times it will save you some headaches if you use toggleClass instead of toggle.  Then you can define in your css classes for visible states, and just toggle those classes.  You'll avoid problems with inline display properties that way.